# Load testing an AI use case/application

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, locust

I'm struggling to understand the steps for measuring the time for a use case built on AI platform to clear the alarms automatically executing a series of commands. Issue is that only task that needs to be done by user is to send an alarm using a async rest api which just gives 200 status & then application starts executing the commands & store time taken for each command in db. I need to measure the complete alarm cycle time.

Steps needed -
1.) Send multiple alarms with a defined spawn-rate & total execution time.
2.) Now run queries to db to get the time taken for each alarm after alarm cycles are completed (need to wait for a while)

Is there any way in existing tools like jmeter or locust which can support measuring time separately as required here? I understand these tools can only support request-response systems. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With JMeter you can organize your test plan as follows:

1. [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) to send an API call
2. [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) to wait until the data is available in the database
3. [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler to periodically check the database for updates
4. Optionally a [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller/) to measure the whole workflow duration

Example test plan outline:

[image]